# How to set event listener for replaceWith()?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Is there any ways to listen to replaceWith event without MutationObserver? because MutationObserver is too complicated

I want to listen this:

```
jQuery( "#elementx" ).replaceWith( "<div id='elementx'><h2>New heading</h2></div>" );
```

I have tried this and doesnt work:

```
jQuery(document).on('change remove detach','#elementx', {} ,function(e){
    alert('elementx changed');
})
```

Comment: why not just alias or clobber .replaceWith() to fire an event when it's used?

Answer (score 0):

Don't be scared of using MutationObserver, for these purposes, it's pretty simple:

```js
console.log('start script');
setTimeout(
  () => $("#elementx").replaceWith("<div id='elementx'><h2>New heading</h2></div>"),
  1000
);
const elementx = $("#elementx")[0];
new MutationObserver(() => {
  if (!elementx.parentElement) {
    console.log('elementx changed');
  }
}).observe(elementx.parentElement, { childList: true });
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="container">
  <div id="elementx">orig elementx</div>
</div>
```

Other (probably worse) options are to monkeypatch `.replaceWith`:

```js
const { replaceWith } = $.fn;
$.fn.replaceWith = function(...args) {
  if (this.is('#elementx')) {
    console.log('elementx changed');
  }
  return replaceWith.apply(this, args);
}

console.log('start script');
setTimeout(
  () => $("#elementx").replaceWith("<div id='elementx'><h2>New heading</h2></div>"),
  1000
);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="container">
  <div id="elementx">orig elementx</div>
</div>
```

Or to use `DOMNodeRemoved`:

```js
document.addEventListener('DOMNodeRemoved', ({ target }) => {
  if (target.id === 'elementx') {
    console.log('elementx removed');
  }
});

console.log('start script');
setTimeout(
  () => $("#elementx").replaceWith("<div id='elementx'><h2>New heading</h2></div>"),
  1000
);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="container">
  <div id="elementx">orig elementx</div>
</div>
```

If this is for a site *you* control, this is a very strange thing to do - better to use a different method, like manually call a function after you call `replaceWith` on the `elementx`.